# How to iterate over Dataframe using a "sliding window" with multi processing (used for genetic algo)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, iterator, python-multiprocessing

Explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish:
I have dataframe to iterate over looking for some condition given a variable.
I have list of variables and I iterate over this df using multiprocessing. I pop(0) everytime a process start.
Now I need to add one more level, but I can't understand how to do it.
Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import decimal
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import itertools 

#dataframe
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
data = np.array([np.random.randint(1, 10_000, size=750)]*4).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= columns)


print(df)
# Creating a list of tuples to apply a given function

a = np.arange(5,20, 1)
b = np.arange(1.01, 1.10, 0.01)
d = np.arange(0.95, 0.99, 0.01)
c = list(itertools.product(a, b, d))

list_of_tuples = []
dic = {}
for x in c:

    dic[(x)] = x


for key, value in dic.items(): 
    uno, due, tre = value[0], value[1], value[2]
    list_of_tuples.append((uno, due, tre))

print(len(dic)) #checking size of dictionary 
print(len(list_of_tuples), len(df)) #checking if size match 

maximum = max(dic, key=dic.get) #maximum key inside dictionary 
print(maximum, dic[maximum])

new_dic = {}
i = 1

#look_back_period = (len(df) // 10)
#print(look_back_period)
c = 0
"""chunks is the only way where I could use pool.map, it should be a list of list"""
chunks = [list_of_tuples[i::len(list_of_tuples)] for i in range(len(list_of_tuples))]
print(len(chunks[0]))
#this manager is needed to have every process append to the same Dict the result of the 
# function that is given below

manager = Manager()
new_dic = manager.dict()



def multi_prova(list_of_tuples): 

    list_results = []

    given1, given2, given3 = list_of_tuples.pop(0)


    #sliding_window = df.iloc[0 : c + look_back_period, : ]

    for row in df.itertuples(): 

        result = (given1 / row.A).round(2)
        list_results.append(result)

    new_dic[str(given1)+', ' + str(given2)+', ' + str(given2)] = result


time1 = time.time()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try: 
        pool = Pool()  # Make the Pool of workers
        results = pool.map(multi_prova, chunks) #Open the urls in their own threads
        pool.close() #close the pool and wait for the work to finish 
        pool.join()
    except: 
        print('error')
time2 = time.time()
print(time2 - time1)

#On my original code len(new_dic) matched len(dic), here is 750 vs 150, don't know why?!?!?!
print(new_dic)
print(len(new_dic))
```

Shouldn't be the len of new_dic == dic
750 rows, and a result for every row to 'append' to the dictionary.
So the problem are two:

why (len(new_dic)) is not 750.
And on top of that I would like to have, a sliding window to iter a slice of dataframe and have a dictionary of list of list with all the result of every slice of the df while c + look_back_period < len(df).

Hope I was clear enough.
A big hug on anyone that can contribute.